# Efficiently Select the latest row grouped by a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
QUOTE
| id | value | mar_id | date |
```

And I am trying to select the latest row for each `mar_id` (market id). I have managed to achieve what I need from the query below:

```
SELECT 
q.*
FROM quote q
WHERE q.date = (
  SELECT MAX(q1.date)
  FROM quote q1
  WHERE q.mar_id = q1.mar_id
)
```

However I find that the query is incredibly slow (>60s), to the extent my database kills the connection.

I did an `EXPLAIN` to find out why and got the result:

[image: Explain Plan]

I have a composite unique index `QUO_UQ` on `mar_id, date` which appears to be getting used.

logically this doesn't seem such a tough query to run, what can I do to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Try executing an uncorrelated subquery instead

Comment: @Strawberry could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of an uncorrelated subquery

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM quote x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT mar_id
            , MAX(date) date
         FROM quote
        GROUP 
           BY mar_id
     ) y
    ON y.mar_id = x.mar_id
   AND y.date = x.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select mar_id, [date],row_number() over (partition by mar_id order by [date] desc ) as [Rank] from
qoute
group by mar_id, [date]) q where Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM quote q
WHERE q.date = (SELECT MAX(q1.date)
                FROM quote q1
                WHERE q.mar_id = q1.mar_id
               );
```

I recommend an index on `quote(mar_id, date)`.  This is probably the fastest method to get your result.

EDIT:

I'm curious if you find that this uses the index:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM quote q
WHERE q.date = (SELECT q1.date
                FROM quote q1
                WHERE q.mar_id = q1.mar_id
                ORDER BY q1.date DESC
                LIMIT 1
               );
```

Comment: I guess the problem is it involves a full table scan, and it still seems to even with an extra index on `mar_id` + `date` :(
The other answers above have partial table scans which seem more efficient

Comment: I'm surprised the index doesn't help as logically it is quite an easy operation to do on a table sorted by mar_id & date. Just pick the first row for each mar_id...